# Format TextBox.Text before sending WebRequest

Tags: c#, wpf, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I have rather very basic question. I would like to send a formated Text from WPF Multiline Textbox to Web application over HttpWebRequest.
Till now I've managed to send plain text, so the connection is working.

As an example, I've created a WPF window with Multiline Textbox and Button in it. When, I press button I would like send the Textbox.Text to WebRequest, but this text should be formated (support breaklines, bold, inclined etc).

```
String _messageString = "message=" + TextBox.Text;
//create authentication string
Byte[] _outBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_messageString ); //store in byte buffer
```

I've narrowed down with Fiddler that the format should be something like this:

```
message=Contrary+to+popular+belief%2C&edttmessage=1
```

So, my question is, how can I transform the Textbox.Text to the above format? Or is there another way do that I should do it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

```
String _messageString = "message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TextBox.Text);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx